# Looping through various excel worksheets for curve fitting in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, curve-fitting

I'm relatively new to performing data analysis with python, thus I'm sorry if this question seems too noob.

I have an excel-file with many different sheets. I've also written a script which fits and plots the data contained in these excel sheets. I have code written to perform curve fitting for only one of the sheets.

My idea was to create a loop that would iterate through all my sheets and apply the script in each one of them at a time, but I'm not really sure how to do this. Could you provide me any guidance, or any place where I could learn/read about how to do this? I have tried to search a bit around but I haven't been able to find anything useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're trying to loop through different sheets of a single excel file. If so, you can use `pd.read_excel`'s `sheet_name` parameter to pass sheets programmatically. (See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

So, if you wanted to loop through the first three sheets, you could use:

```py
for i in range(3):
    df = pd.read_excel('path/to/file.xlsx', sheet_name=i)
    do_stuff(df)
```

Comment: Upvoted for the clarity and excellence of the answer.